# Assembler memory allocation

Tags: memory, assembly, masm

I was trying to solve this problem for a few days. I have no idea how to allocate memory to copy string into another location. Here's the code:

```
caesarAsm proc string: DWORD, key: DWORD, stringLength : DWORD

        ; inside this procedure I have a code that ciphers string value using caesar cipher 


        mov eax, string
        ret         
caesarAsm endp
```

Then in CPP file when I use the function:

```
caesar1(word, 13, strlen(word))
```

It changes the value of word as is was passed by reference. I want it to do nothing until I'll do:

```
word = caesar1(word, 13, strlen(word))
```

I was been trying to solve this problem searching all over the Internet, but I found nothing helpful. I guess that solution is simple, but I cannot find it. I was trying to do sth with ESI and EDI registers. 
I guess I have to allocate new memory then copy the string into this allocated location. How to do it?

Comment: Use [one of the memory allocation functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533(v=vs.85).aspx) provided by Windows.

Comment: I tried. No one of those functions works for me (or I don't know how to use them).

Comment: Generally, you either use the functions provided by the [C runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59ey50w6.aspx) or the relevant system calls.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it using x86 assembler functions?

Comment: Generally, memory is reserved in the `.bss` section to hold the copied string. (e.g. `str2 resb 19` to reserve 19 bytes of memory under the label `str2`) You then load the address of the first sting in `esi` and your destination string in `edi` and use `rep movsb` to copy from source to destination.

Comment: When I try to do anything in .bss section I get:
1>caesarAsm.asm(25): error A2008: syntax error : .
1>caesarAsm.asm(26): error A2008: syntax error : str2

Comment: Use `lea` to load the effective address of each string in the registers. e.g. `lea     esi, [str1]`  `lea     edi, [str2]` then load the number of chars to copy in `cx` (e.g. `mov     cx, 19`), then call `rep     movsb`. (this is with nasm/intel syntax)

Comment: But how can I get address of str2?.bss and resb doesn't work

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: MASM, x86 in Microsoft Visual Studio, .586

Comment: Your syntax will be slightly different, but the approach will be the same. I'll add a short example.

Comment: _"I tried. No one of those functions works for me (or I don't know how to use them)."_ That's not of much help to us unless you show how you attempted to use them.

Comment: I can't find a way to use them, my MASM doesn't know them.

Comment: The assembler doesn't know about any Win32 API functions unless you include the required `.inc` file and link against the required `.lib` file. MSDN lists in which library a given function exists.

Answer (score 1):

Following from the discussion in the comments, the basic approach to copy a string is to declare a label in .bss and reserve the number of bytes required to hold the copy of the string. This is using intel syntax as I do not have MASM available. As an example, you can declare your original string in .data. e.g.:

```
section .data
    str_str1 db 'string one to copy', 0

section .bss
    str_str2 resb 19
```

For the copy, load the address of `str_str1` into `esi` and the address of `str_str2` in `edi`. Load the number of characters to copy in `cx` and then call `rep movsb` to move the number of bytes specified in `cx` from `esi` to `edi`. e.g.:

```
section .text
                global _start

        _start:
                xor     ecx, ecx            ; clear ecx
                cld                         ; clear direction flag (read L->R)
                lea     esi, [str_str1]     ; load str1 in esi
                lea     edi, [str_str2]     ; load str2 in edi
                mov     cx, 19              ; move 19 into cx for repeat
        rep     movsb                       ; move 19 bytes from str1 -> str2

        exit:
                xor     edi, edi            ; set zero exit code
                mov     eax, 1              ; set int 0x80 number to 60 (0x3c hex)
                int 0x80                    ; call kernel
```

That will copy `str_str` to `str_str2`. You can then add the code to print them, etc. Nasm offers a simple macro language to help with repetitive tasks like read calls and write calls (especially for indents, spacing, printing, etc)  The complete example in nasm syntax is:

```
; Following macros simply print indents, newlines and strings to stdout
%macro  indent  1
        mov     eax, 4
        mov     ebx, 1
        mov     ecx, tab
        mov     edx, %1
        int 0x80
%endmacro

%macro  newlns  1
        mov     eax, 4
        mov     ebx, 1
        mov     ecx, onln
        mov     edx, %1
        int 0x80
%endmacro

; strn (string const) macro is overloaded to take 1 or 2 args
%macro  strn    1
        mov     eax, 4
        mov     ebx, 1
        mov     ecx, %1
        mov     edx, 1
        int 0x80
%endmacro

%macro  strn    2
        mov     eax, 4
        mov     ebx, 1
        mov     ecx, %1
        mov     edx, %2
        int 0x80
%endmacro

section .data

    nwln db 0xa
    dnln db 0xa,0xa
    onln times 8 db 0xa     ; 8 newlines
    tab times 8 db 0x20     ; 8 spaces
    msg_str1 db 0xa, '  string_1: '
    msg_str2 db 0xa, '  string_2: '

    str_str1 db 'string one to copy', 0

section .bss

    str_str2 resb 19

section .text
                global _start

        _start:
                xor     ecx, ecx            ; clear ecx
                cld                         ; clear direction flag (read L->R)
                lea     esi, [str_str1]     ; load str1 in esi
                lea     edi, [str_str2]     ; load str2 in edi
                mov     cx, 19              ; move 19 into cx for repeat
        rep     movsb                       ; move 19 bytes from str1 -> str2

                ; macros to print results & add newlines
                strn    msg_str1, 13        ; print str1 msg
                strn    str_str1, 19        ; print str1
                strn    msg_str2, 13        ; print str2 msg
                strn    str_str2, 19        ; print str2
                newlns  2                   ; print 2 newlines

        exit:
                xor     edi, edi            ; set zero exit code
                mov     eax, 1              ; set int 0x80
                int 0x80                    ; call kernel
```

**Nasm compile/link**

```
nasm -f elf -o obj/str_cpy_32.o str_cpy_32.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o bin/str_cpy_32 obj/str_cpy_32.o
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_cpy_32

  string_1: string one to copy
  string_2: string one to copy
```

Look at the MASM syntax differences and make the needed changes. There should be no reason you shouldn't be able to accomplish the exact same thing.

**Determining String Size - 32-bit**

As discussed, to determine the length of an unknown string, the string itself must be null-terminated to provide an end sentinel character to test. The string address is placed in `edi` and then you effectively check each character for zero (numeric zero, not character zero) and the length is determined by the number of iterations it takes to reach the null-terminating character:

```
; szstr computes the length of a string.
; edi - string address
; edx - contains string length (returned)
section .text
    strsz:
            xor     ecx, ecx    ; zero rcx
            not     ecx         ; set rcx = -1 (uses bitwise id: ~x = -x-1)
            xor     al,al       ; zero the al register (initialize to NUL)
            cld                 ; clear the direction flag
            repnz   scasb       ; get the string length (dec ecx through NUL)
            not     ecx         ; rev all bits of negative -> absolute value
            dec     ecx         ; -1 to skip the null-term, ecx contains length
            mov     edx, ecx    ; size returned in edx, ready to call write
            ret
```

Of course, you do not have to use it as a function, you can just put the code in the body of your assembly program, but since it is something you use often, it helps to use it as a function.

Comment: I found information that i can use DW in .data section to create place for text. But when I'm starting program I don't know length of my string. How can I get it from proc caesarAsm? Can I allocate memory inside the procedure using variable length?

Comment: For stings that you do not declare in data and can't grab the length from the offset, you will need to loop over the string until you find the `0` null-terminator. I'll see if I have a 32-bit function for that and post it in the example.

Comment: I have the length saved in stringLength : DWORD, but I don't know how to allocate stringLength-bytes of memory inside .code section.

Comment: The easiest way would simply be to reserve space for a DWORD in either .data or .bss and assign a label to that address. In data you need to initialize the value, '0000' is fine, then write the length to the label address once it is computed.

Comment: I just have to say that you should have mentioned that you were using Linux back when people were telling you to use the Windows memory allocation functions.  "They won't work" isn't nearly as informative as "I'm not using Windows."  What's even more suspicious is that you talk of using Visual Studio with MASM..  Yet your code is definitely Linux specific.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. The chronology of the comments clearly explains that the example provides nasm/intel syntax for which the OP was to find the equivalent in masm and were provided per request. What part of that is unclear?

Comment: I am using Windows. When I initialize value '0000' in .data section and then write next bytes to memory without reserving it, would it work without problems? I mean if are there gonna be any memory problems?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. You must make sure you are using the syntax to write to the address in memory as opposed to the address of the label. In nasm '[]' around the label makes that distinction. I don't know what is needed with masm, but that should be easy to find.